# return lines with matching pattern from a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a perl script to extract the lines matching different patterns and then operate onto it. I've done following to match and extracts all the lines which contain the matching pattern:

```
my $filetoread = <$curr_dir/p*.out>;
my $filetoreadStrings=`strings $filetoread | egrep \"(Preparing extraction | 100.00%)\"`;
my @ftr = split('\n', $filetoreadStrings);
chomp (@ftr);

my $FirstPattern = (grep /Preparing extraction/, @ftr)[0];
my $SecondPattern = (grep /100.00% done/, @ftr)[0];
print "$FirstPattern \n";
print "$SecondPattern \n";
```

I'm getting lines with the second pattern only, even though the first pattern (Preparing extraction) is present in the log. I think the problem is with or '|'. I need to know how to get all the lines matching the patterns.
[$curr_dir is the directory I'm running the script from and P*.out is the log file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`... egrep \"(Preparing extraction | 100.00%)\" ...`
```

should be

```
`... egrep \"(Preparing extraction| 100.00%)\" ...`
```

or just

```
`... egrep "(Preparing extraction| 100.00%)" ...`
```

---

```
my $filetoread = <$curr_dir/p*.out>;
```

should be

```
my ($filetoread) = <$curr_dir/p*.out>;
```

Don't call `<glob_pattern>` in scalar context unless you call it until it returns undef.

---

```
my @ftr = split '\n', `...`;
chomp(@ftr);
```

should be

```
my @ftr = split /\n/, `...`;
```

or

```
chomp( my @ftr = `...` );
```

Comment: Hey thanks!! it worked. So it was an extra space between 'or'? Also can you explain me the reason for "my ($filetoread)".

Comment: I did explain, but I'll add: cause it'll cause any later glob in your program to work incorrectly if you don't.